# Http Get returns Error

Tags: angular, http, typescript, get

I have an angular component which should do a simple HTTP Get:

```
this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:80/userservice/login', { params: { username: this.model.username, password: this.model.password } })
        .subscribe(
        data => {
            this.router.navigate(['/register']);
        },
        error => {
            this.alertService.error(error.message);
            this.loading = false;
        });
```

And a webservice in Java which should response to the request:

```
@GET @Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ) @Path("/login")
public Response login(@QueryParam("username") String username, @QueryParam("password") String password)
{
   return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).header("Content-type", "application/json").entity("test").build();
}
```

But Angular always goes into the error section of the subscription instead of the data subscription.

> Error-Message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error”

I already checked with breakpoints that my Java Server successfully receives the requests and then sends back the response.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help!

Comment: What’s the error you got back from the call?

Comment: What does error message say?

Comment: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error”

Comment: Have you tried looking at the request and the response in your browser's developer tools?

Comment: have you check your CORS, check response from backend service if there is Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present or not. you need to add 'always' parameter to make sure header is added regardless of the response code like 'http://localhost:4200' always;

Comment: I saw in the Browser Developer Tools that the Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header was missing. I added it and now everything works fine. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was that:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin='*'
```

was missing in the Header. This prevented Angular accessing the Response.